# Trying to use text to columns function (delimited) on 2 workbooks but getting error

Tags: excel, vba

As stated above im trying to use the text to columns function but am getting errors

```
Sub Matt_Liam()

     Worksheets("orders (3)").Range("X1:AO300").Cut Worksheets("orders (3)").Range("Z1:AQ300") 'Makes room for texttocolumns

        Dim objRange1 As Range
    With Workbooks("orders (3).xlsx").Worksheets("orders (3)")
        Set objRange1 = .Range("W1:W300")
        objRange1.TextToColumns _
        Destination:=.Range("W1"), _
        DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, _
        Comma:=False, _
        Space:=False, _
        Other:=True, _
        OtherChar:="|"
    End With


    Worksheets("orders (3)").Range("A1:AY300").Copy Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:AY300") 'moves to sheet1
    Workbooks("orders (3).xlsx").Worksheets("orders (3)").Range("A1:AY300").Copy _
    Workbooks("Book1").Worksheets("Production").Range("A1:AY300") 'Copy 'moves to production workbook
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Workbooks("Book1").Worksheets("Production").Range("A:U").Clear  'clears uneeded columns in production workbook
    Workbooks("Book1").Worksheets("Production").Range("AB:AY").Clear

    Workbooks("Book1").Worksheets("Production").Range("V1:AA300").Cut _
    Workbooks("Book1").Worksheets("Production").Range("A1:F300")  'cleans up prodcution workbook

    Workbooks("Book1").Worksheets("Production").Range("D1:F300").Cut _
    Workbooks("Book1").Worksheets("Production").Range("E1:G300")  'cleans up prodcution workbook

    Workbooks("Book1").Worksheets("Production").Range("F1:G300").Cut _
    Workbooks("Book1").Worksheets("Production").Range("G1:H300")  'cleans up prodcution workbook

        Dim objRange2 As Range
        With Workbooks("Book1.xlsx").Worksheets("Production")
        Set objRange2 = .Range("C2:C300")
        objRange2.TextToColumns _
        Destination:=.Range("C2"), _
        DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, _
        Comma:=False, _
        Space:=False, _
        Other:=True, _
        OtherChar:=":"
    End With



    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:AY").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide uneeded columns on sheet1
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B:B").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("T:T").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("V:V").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("W:W").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("X:X").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("Y:Y").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("Z:Z").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("AA:AA").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("AB:AB").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("AD:AD").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("AF:AF").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("AI:AI").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("AL:AL").EntireColumn.Hidden = False

Dim rw As Long, lastrow As Long, MySel As Range 'Grabs skus and moves to new sheet

With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    For rw = 1000 To 2 Step -1
        If .Cells(rw, 26).Value Like "*22-*" Then
            If MySel Is Nothing Then
                Set MySel = .Cells(rw, 1).EntireRow
            Else
                Set MySel = Union(MySel, .Cells(rw, 1).EntireRow)
            End If
        End If
    Next rw
End With

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    If Not MySel Is Nothing Then
        MySel.Copy Destination:=.Cells(lastrow + 1, 1)
        'MySel.Delete
    End If
End With


End Sub
```

I'm getting the error:

> Subscript out of range on line 38

Comment: What line is line 38? They aren't numbered here.

Comment: Its the second text to column:         Dim objRange2 As Range
        With Workbooks("Book1.xlsx").Worksheets("Production")
        Set objRange2 = .Range("C2:C300")
        objRange2.TextToColumns _
        Destination:=.Range("C2"), _
        DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, _
        Comma:=False, _
        Space:=False, _
        Other:=True, _
        OtherChar:=":"
    End With

Comment: remove the .xlsx from ```Workbooks("Book1.xlsx")```.

Comment: that worked. Thanks so much for the help again